# Polar decomposition in a C*-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras

**Problem:** Let $A$ be a $C^∗$-algebra and let $x \in A$ be such that $0$ is an
isolated point of the spectrum of $x^∗x$. Show that $x$ has polar decomposition in $A$, i.e. the polar part of $x$ lies in $A$.

I have no idea how to proceed, although I suspect that you have to use continuous functional calculus on $x^* x$ at some point. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\{0\}$ is isolated in $\sigma(x^\ast x)$, it is also isolated in $\sigma(|x|)$ and we may define continuous $f: \sigma(|x|) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $f(t) = 1/t$ when $t \neq 0$ and $f(t) = 0$ when $t = 0$. Then $f(|x|) \in A$ and you can define $u = xf(|x|)$. You can then verify that $x = u|x|$ is the polar decomposition of $x$.

Comment: Excellent, just one question.How do you prove that $\ker u = \ker |x|$, which is part of the requirement for polar decomposition?

Comment: @the_dude The projection onto the kernel of $|x|$ is exactly $g(|x|)$ where $g(t) = 1$ when $t = 0$ and $g(t) = 0$ otherwise. So the projection onto $\ker(|x|)^\perp$ is $h(|x|)$ where $h(t) = 0$ when $t = 0$ and $h(t) = 1$ otherwise. A direct calculation tells you $u^\ast u = h(|x|)$. Since $u$ is a partial isometry, $u^\ast u$ is exactly the projection onto the orthogonal complement of its kernel, so $\ker(u) = \ker(|x|)$.

Comment: It is your first sentence I'm having trouble with. Could you elaborate a little?

Comment: @the_dude If you’re unaware of that fact, this would require more than just a few comments to explain. Let’s continue this discussion under your new post, which seems to be exactly about this issue.